# Why the following code is not giving double free error?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

When I do two consecutive `free()`'s on same pointer it is giving double free error but when I try to free the same pointer two times in between i freed other pointer it is not giving  the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
int main (){                                                                               
   long int*ptr;                                                              
    int *ptr1;                                                                  

    ptr = malloc (1);                                                           
    ptr1 = malloc (1);                                                          

    printf ("%ld\n", ptr[-1]);                                                  
    free (ptr);                                                                 
    printf ("%ld\n", ptr[-1]);                                                  
    free (ptr1);                                                                
    free (ptr);                                                                 
    free (ptr1);                                                                
    free (ptr);                                                                 
    free (ptr1);                                                                
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: double free does not have to give a error in the first place

Comment: This is simply undefined behaviour.

Comment: *** Error in `./app': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000563f04897010 ***

Comment: C is allowing you to do many bad things. Voiding the warranty, of course..

Answer (score 6):

There's no promise made that a double `free` will cause a segmentation fault.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> `free()` frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must  have 
>   been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. 
>   **Otherwise, or  if  `free(ptr)`  has  already  been  called  before, 
>   undefined behaviour occurs.**  If `ptr` is `NULL`, no operation is
>   performed.

[Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means there are no guarantees regarding what will happen.  Your program may crash, it may exhibit strange behavior, or (as you've seen) it could appear to work correctly.  Making a seemingly unrelated change to your code can change how undefined behavior manifests itself, so it could start crashing or it could stop crashing.

EDIT:

Running a program through a tool such as Valgrind, as suggested by Toby, puts additional checks in place specifically to look for these types of errors and will tell you exactly where things are going wrong.

Without such a tool however, if you invoke undefined behavior all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're using the wrong tool to test your program.  Valgrind certainly reports plenty of errors when I built your test program:

```
gcc -std=c11 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds      41147878.c    -o 41147878
valgrind  ./41147878 
==30744== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30744== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30744== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30744== Command: ./41147878
==30744== 
==30744== Invalid read of size 8
==30744==    at 0x10876C: main (41147878.c:10)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5038 is 8 bytes before a block of size 1 alloc'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x108751: main (41147878.c:7)
==30744== 
0
==30744== Invalid read of size 8
==30744==    at 0x108797: main (41147878.c:12)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5038 is 8 bytes before a block of size 1 free'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x10878E: main (41147878.c:11)
==30744==  Block was alloc'd at
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x108751: main (41147878.c:7)
==30744== 
0
==30744== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087C5: main (41147878.c:14)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x10878E: main (41147878.c:11)
==30744==  Block was alloc'd at
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x108751: main (41147878.c:7)
==30744== 
==30744== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087D1: main (41147878.c:15)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087B9: main (41147878.c:13)
==30744==  Block was alloc'd at
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x10875F: main (41147878.c:8)
==30744== 
==30744== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087DD: main (41147878.c:16)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x10878E: main (41147878.c:11)
==30744==  Block was alloc'd at
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x108751: main (41147878.c:7)
==30744== 
==30744== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087E9: main (41147878.c:17)
==30744==  Address 0x51d5090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 free'd
==30744==    at 0x4C2BDDB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x1087B9: main (41147878.c:13)
==30744==  Block was alloc'd at
==30744==    at 0x4C2ABAF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30744==    by 0x10875F: main (41147878.c:8)
==30744== 
==30744== 
==30744== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30744==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30744==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 7 frees, 1,026 bytes allocated
==30744== 
==30744== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30744== 
==30744== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30744== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If you were using some other checker to conduct your test, you should edit the question to be more specific.